# Edition value in Scratch Org Definition File for Unlimited org

Tags: salesforcedx

Which is the correct value for the field edition in the Scratch Org Definition File for an Unlimited org?

The documentation in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm says:

> edition:  Valid entries are Developer, Enterprise, Group, or
>   Professional

And in https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=overview_edition.htm&type=0:

> **Unlimited Edition**
>   This edition is Salesforce’s solution for maximizing
>   your success and extending that success across the entire enterprise
>   through the Force.com platform. Unlimited Edition customers benefit
>   from new levels of platform flexibility for managing and sharing all
>   their information on demand. **Unlimited Edition includes all Enterprise
>   Edition functionality** plus Premier Support, full mobile access,
>   unlimited custom apps, increased storage limits, and more.

Should I use Enterprise? Has anyone faced this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One line answer is **Unlimited** is not supported so use Enterprise as value

[image]

As this is mentioned clearly in [**doc**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm) possible values are:

- Developer
- Enterprise
- Group
- Professional